# ELK-logstash.conf is always wrong

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I want use Filebeat with logstash.But the logstash.conf is wrong.

logstash.conf:

```

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}
```

```

It reponse this:

Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 3, column 1 (byte 76) after ", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:50:in`compile_graph'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:12:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in`map'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `compile_sources'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:51:in`initialize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:171:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in`execute'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:335:in `block in converge_state'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in`with_pipelines'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:332:in `block in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in`each'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:319:in `converge_state'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in`block in converge_state_and_update'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in`converge_state_and_update'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in `execute'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:343:in`block in execute'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beats plugin is wrong. The port should be a number.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html

Also you have no filter plugin, maybe that will be necessary too:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }
}
filter{}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}
```